# String with superscript character does not match using testng in Intellij, but does using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I'm using testng/Selenium/java and am giving Intellij a try (I've been using Eclipse).  Ran into a problem using IntelliJ that worked perfectly in Eclipse and I can't figure out what's going on.

The lines in question are:

```
    sellunitcubeimpText = driver.findElement(By.id("sellUnitCubeImp_Label")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(sellunitcubeimpText, String.valueOf(df.format(Double.parseDouble(sellunitcubeText) * 35.3146667)) + "ft³");
```

sellunitcubeimpText in IntelliJ shows as: "26.6096ftï¿½" which is incorrect.  In Eclipse it properly shows as: "26.6096ft³".

The result of the String.valueOf.... in IntelliJ shows as: "26.6096ftÂ³" which as you can see is incorrect.  However, in Eclipse it again shows properly as "26.6096ft³".

Why is Eclipse properly handling this string and IntelliJ isn't?

Comment: Are they using different fonts?

Comment: Well, considering it's a java function that's failing, would the display font have anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe we need screen shots?

Comment: Here is the debug output in IntelliJ:  java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :26.6096ftï¿½
Actual   :26.6096ftÂ³
  <Click to see difference>


 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
 at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:496)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:178)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:188)
 at com.ip.tests.StartQuote.testStartQuote(StartQuote.java:925)